# How can I fix internet connection issues on wsl2

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just got on wsl2 and when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error `archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:503:83eb::30). - connect (101: Network is unreachable`. What am I missing here?

**Note**: I am on the official release to the public windows-10 updates 2004

distro `ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

According to old similar issues I should disable Avast, well in my case I don't have avast installed

This is all the error

```
bihire@DESKTOP-UJES0GS:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for bihire:
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [101 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [37.8 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2612 B]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [2972 B]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [34.1 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [16.6 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1428 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1172 B]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Translation-en [540 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:503:a83e::2:30). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

Comment: WSL inherits the Windows network settings.  Does your computer have IPv6 enabled on it for its network connections in the adapter settings?

Comment: do I need to enable more than [this picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VA2VKspa_ORg7GFM6WsDhslwBu3dwwja/view?usp=sharing) @ThomasWard

Comment: No, but I was asking because in Ubuntu if it sees an IPv6 connection available it will try and *use* the IPv6 connection (so therefore you may want to consider disabling IPv6 support in Windows on the interface unless you need it).  Alternatively, try and force the use of IPv4 per [this Unix and Linux post/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100887/5807) within WSL.

Comment: disabled IPv6 still the same output [this picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CRNYyAhRuaR9Ic69KZAkE4bD9EpeBEJ/view?usp=sharing) @ThomasWard

Comment: You may probably want to ask this in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same issue. As the comment above suggested I disabled IPv6 option for both, my **wireless adapter** and **WSL Ethernet** adapter.

Follow the steps:

1. Right click on your network icon, and click on *Open Network and Internet settings*
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQYe.png)
2. In the settings page look for *Change adapter options* under *Advanced Network settings*
   [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKQv5.png)
3. On the next page you'll see a bunch of network adapters, for bluetooth, vpns, ethernet and for wifi.
4. If you use wifi, then disable IPv6 for wifi and wsl adapters.
5. Right click on the adapter and click *Properties*
6. In the pop up look for a checkbox specifying IPv6 connection, uncheck it. [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9sww.png)

I was trying to comment at first then couldn't (less reputations).

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: does not work!!

Answer (score 3):

For me it was the Symantec Endpoint Protection agent that was blocking IP traffic to/from WSL2.
In the app, go to menu Change Settings > configure settings for Network and Host Exploit Mitigation > and select the option Allow IP traffic.

Comment: Not a global solution but yes, Definitely worked for me as Symantec was causing the issue in first place!

Answer (score 3):

I had mine working as a miner, both Ubuntu and Debian, changed Internet providers and both stop connecting to the mining pool and couldn't do the update or upgrades.

The easy fix was:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and changing `nameserver` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 2):

With my latest windows 10 ver 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1165) and the latest WSL2 Ubuntu-18.04. (On windows 11 Insider ver 21H2 (OS Build 22000.168) and **fresh** install of wsl2 ubuntu 18.04 it works well, the .wslconfig is correctly set with **swapfile=0**, it could be that when upgrading on the windows 10 from wsl1 to wsl2, since the .wslconfig was already there, that it was not freshly created correctly).

Thus, the simple procedure that works is to modify the c:\users%USERPROFILE%.wslconfig file to be:

```
[wsl2]    
memory=8GB    
**swapFile=0**    
swap=0
```

c:> wsl --shutdown
c:> wsl

For some reason someone at microsoft changed the name of the swap config parameter. Stragely, when swapfile=0 is defined. wsl2's network works like a whistle.

**Microsoft**: Please decouple swalfile from network. And consider supporting both names for the swap.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  While this is useful information, you may want to phrase this as an *alternative* answer for readers for whom the other answers aren't working.  Obviously, this is a *new* change as you mention, so it isn't the answer to the original question that was asked a year ago.  So no, it isn't the "simple procedure that works" for everyone, obviously :)  You should also point out which version of Windows this changed in, so that readers can check if that might be the problem.  It wouldn't be useful for someone on an older release to try to update to the newer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had same experience with ubuntu distro wsl 2 (win10):

```
No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Release:        20.04

Codename:       focal
```

What I did is I updated the etc/hosts.

- edit your hosts: sudo vi etc/hosts
- find the following lines that **are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts** then comment those lines. No need to disable IPv6 in your network.

  ```
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

  fe00::0 ip6-localnet

  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix

  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  ```
- save (esc + x )
- try ping google.com

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Adapter settings]

Disabling LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver solved this for me, HP ProBook Laptop, Windows 11.